# POST request with content type multipart/form-data with adding extra header at the AWS API GATEWAY

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, post, aws-api-gateway, mime-types

I have an AWS api gateway and i want to send a post request or any other request if possible when content type is multipart/form-data, the problem is that i want to add a conditional extra header at the api gateway level using template mappings, i was able to do this with GET request and content type is application/json, but the same code i applied doesn't seem to work when request is POST and content type is multipart/form-data, so how can i add an extra header when using different content tyes or different requests at the api gateway level ? my code that worked is this :

```
#set($header3Value = "service1")
$input.json("$")
#set($context.requestOverride.header.x-service-key = $header3Value)
#elseif
($method.request.header.x-api-key == "*******************nmMBBkbbkBVCXvjhvhkk")
#set($header3Value = "service1")
$input.json("$")
#set($context.requestOverride.header.x-service-key = $header3Value)
#elseif
($method.request.header.x-api-key == "*****IHOHMubbbVYVYUVVVVLkbkbbbmmlb")
#set($header3Value = "service2")
$input.json("$")
#set($context.requestOverride.header.x-service-key = $header3Value)
#end
```

Edit : When I prepare a template mapping for multipart/form-data with the same code i used for Application/json, i get "internal server error" with no other info, but when i empty the template and leave it blank, it goes back to working but of course, the custom header i want to add won't be added ...